# Formatting Axes of Binned Temporal (Continuous) Bar Graphs

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega

I'm having some issues formatting the x-axis of binned temporal bar graphs.

Here is the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

c1 = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01",end="2021-02-15")
c2 = np.random.randint(1,6, size=len(c1))
df = pd.DataFrame({"day": c1, "value": c2})
df = df.drop(np.random.choice(df.index, size=12, replace=False))
```

Here is one approach, let's call this `A`. This uses a `timeUnit` to bin the data, but behind the scenes it uses `x`/`x2` encoding.

```
c1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode\
    ( alt.X("monthdate(day):T")
    , alt.Y("value")
    )

t1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(baseline="bottom").encode\
    ( alt.X("monthdate(day):T")
    , alt.Y("value")
    , alt.Text("value")
    )

(c1 + t1).interactive(bind_y=False).properties(width=800)
```

Here is another approach, let's call this `B`. This uses `x`/`x2` encoding directly.

```
c2 = alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate\
    ( day = "toDate(datum.day)"
    , start = "datum.day - 12*60*60*1000"
    , end = "datum.day + 12*60*60*1000"
    ).mark_bar().encode\
    ( alt.X("start:T")
    , alt.X2("end:T")
    , alt.Y("value")
    )

t2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(baseline="bottom").encode\
    ( alt.X("day:T")
    , alt.Y("value")
    , alt.Text("value")
    )

(c2 + t2).interactive(bind_y=False).properties(width=800)
```

Each has their share of formatting issues, with much overlap.

A (`timeUnit`):

1. Align the text marks, axis labels, and axis ticks to the center of the bar marks. Is it possible to offset either the axis or the data by a data-dependent or zoom-dependent amount? For example axis `offset` is in pixels and therefore unsuitable. Vega offers `xOffset` [encoding](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/mark.html#offset), but that might [not be available](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4703) to Altair. It's a pity that `band` or `bandPosition` fields don't work with continuous domains.
2. There should be just one tick, one grid, and one label per bar. I can solve this in vega-lite using `"axis": {"tickCount": "day"}` but this generates a schema error in Altair 4.1.0.
3. Unique axis label formatting on year and month transitions, including linebreaks within axis labels. I believe a registered custom format type will allow me to use a custom JavaScript function, but I could use an example.
4. Change the axis labels based on how many bars are visible at the current zoom level. For example, to add the weekday at high zoom levels. According to [this](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1310#issuecomment-524296270) it is possible. I'm not sure how, but it probably involves an `alt.Condition` on the axis format field. This format field is then passed to the custom format function (above, `A.3`).

B (`x`/`x2`):

1. Half-sized grid every now and then. See screenshots. This is pretty strange. *edit: Apparently also an issue with `A`, judging by the screenshots below. Never noticed it till now.*
2. Missing or inconsistent dividers between bars. A possible solution is to add `alt.X(..., bin="binned")`, but this removes the grid verticals and I haven't looked into adding them back. I don't want to reduce the `x1`-`x2` width because that leads to an undesirable zoom-dependent gap.
3. Inconsistent axis labels. I've seen four separate label formats at once on the x-axis, and it's even more confusing than it appears: `%a %d`, `%Y`, `%b %d`, `%B`. It's weird that this isn't an issue with code version `A`. Hopefully this is fixed with a custom format function as in `A.3`. I see that vega's `scale/encode/labels/update/text` ties a `timeFormat` to the signal handler. Is that the same thing as a custom format function?
4. Same as `A.2`.
5. Same as `A.3`.
6. Same as `A.4`.

Here are the images documenting all these problems:

A (`timeUnit`):

[image: enumeration of all temporal-binning problems with image and text]

B (`x`/`x2`):

[image: enumeration of all x1/x2 problems with image and text]

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: Thanks for the edit I think the answer is "You can't change the fundamental ways that Vega-Lite renders axes". If you want pixel-level control of how axes are rendered, Altair/Vega-Lite is probably not the right tool for you. Also, the reason Altair does not support `{"tickCount": "day"}` is that it was introduced very recently in Vega-Lite, and Altair hasn't yet updated to support that version.

Comment: Does the Altair version correspond to the Vega-lite schema version? Support for `TimeInterval`s in `tickCount` was added in 4.10.2 but 3 years ago in Vega.

Comment: You're saying `A.2` is just a matter of time, but `A.1` is not solvable (at least not without `xOffset`) which means I must use `B`. I assume `B.2` is easy to solve and `B.3` is tied to `A.3`. Which just leaves `A.3` and `A.4`. Should I ask these as separate questions? I haven't had much luck writing a [custom `formatType`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html), and I have no idea how to query the number of visible data points.

Comment: For example, the vega-lite [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/config.html#custom-format-type) refers to `vega.expressionFunction` while the Altair [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/usage/compile.html#format-type) links to `vegaLite.compile` but neither of these seem to exist for Altair.

Comment: The version of Vega-Lite supported by any given version of altair can be seen in `alt.VEGALITE_VERSION`. Vega-Lite does not provide versioned documentation, so all links in the Altair docs are to the latest Vega-Lite version. It's not ideal, but is preferable to having no links at all.